# How to use 2 data series in a bar graphic (stacked bars) with a Chart component in C#

Tags: c#

I have a table with data about telephone calls received, accepted and reject per month and I want to make abar graphic using a Char component in a C# programa. I know how to do it for show one data series (i.e: the phone calls received) but I woul like to show in the seame bar graphic 2 data series (the accepted cal an the reject calls). Some similar as the image below:

[image]

Does anybody know if is this possible in C#?
Thanks you

Comment: What charts component are you using?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

Comment: Looks like a stacked charttype. Do make sure the x-values are actually meaningful, ie number or datetimes and not just strings!!!

Comment: Then have a look at [Chart.Series Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.series?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code makes what I was looking for:

//  First we clear the Chart

```
chtCalls.Titles.Clear();
chtCalls.Series.Clear();
```

// Then we define our chart

```
chtCalls.Series.Add("Series1");
chtCalls.Series.Add("Series2");         
chtCalls.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn; 
chtCalls.Series["Series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
chtCallss.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 100;

chtCalls.Titles.Add("Received calls per Time Shift ");
chtCalls.Series["Series1"].LegendText = "Attended calls";
chtCalls.Series["Series2"].LegendText = "Rejected calls";
```

//Now we collect the data series

```
foreach (ClassCall calls in myList)
{ chtCalls.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(calls.TheDay.ToShortDateString(), calls.Attended);
                chtCalls.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(calls.TheDay.ToShortDateString(), calls.Rejected);
```

}